# Razor: How to create a dropdown out of an IEnumerable<string> ViewBag property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I have the following to render a view:

```
 public ActionResult CreateAlta()
        {
            ViewBag.RolesApp = new SQLRolerecord().GetAllRolesInApp();
            return View();
        }
```

How can generate a dropdown menu from the ViewBag property RolesApp? `GetAllRolesInApp()` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and my attempt is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role: </label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor("iroleeid", ViewBag.RolesApp, "--Select Role of User--");
          </div>
</div>
```

However this generates an error saying `DropDownListFor` does not exist in the HtmlHelper.

Thank You.

Comment: You could convert your IENumerable to a SelectList. What does your Role model looks like? Id and Name?

Comment: Do you mean instead of `string` use `SelectList`? My Role model is AppRole, which is based on the IdentityRole class of the Identity framework.

Comment: Yes, a SelectListItem contains a Text and a Value, store the string you want to display at the `Text` property, you can store a unique value in `Value` to differentiate between multiple SelectListItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the list of strings to a list of `SelectListItem`'s

```
var roles = new SQLRolerecord().GetAllRolesInApp()
                               .Select(f=>new SelectListItem { Value=f, Text = f}).ToList();
ViewBag.Roles= roles ;
```

Now in your view, you can use the `DropDownList` helper method.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Roles")
```

This will generate a select element with `name` and `id` property values set to `"Roles"`. If you want those to be a different name, use this overload.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole",ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>)
```

This will create a dropdown with name and id property value set to `"SelectedRole"`

Since we are setting the Value and Text of `SelectListItem` object to same string value, your select element option value and text will be same

Comment: Trying this, I get the error `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedRole'. ` when loading the page.

Comment: That is impossible ! Are you sure you have the **second parameter** as well ? The second parameter specify the option items explicitly

Comment: Never mind, you are right. When I copied things over, I messed up on the name of the ViewBag property, because in my code, it was called `RolesApp`. Thanks for the reply and this is a working answer.

Comment: No problem. BTW, I updated the answer to include both the overloads.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a `DropDownListFor` but that expects you to have a view model and a property attached to that (using a lambda). I think you are looking for a     `DropDownList`

```
@Html.DropDownList("iroleeid",
                new SelectList(ViewBag.RolesApp),
                "--Select Role of User--",
                new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `IENumerable<Role>` to a `SelectList`.

Controller:

```
var selectList = new SqlRoleRecord().GetAllRolesInApp().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Name }).ToList();
ViewBag.RolesApp = selectList;
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedRoleId, ViewBag.RolesApp, Model.SelectedRoleId)
```

---

Optional:

When you add a property for storing the SelectedRoleId to your model, you can use it later on in your controller. Useful when you do need to bind the role to a user in the database for example.

---

P.S. Not sure if 100% working, can't compile at this moment.

Comment: I tried this, however, I got an error saying that string does not contain a definition for Id or Name. I think this is is because my GetAllRolesInApp does not return a list of models, but rather a list of strings.

Comment: @ITWorker Id and Name are examples. You should set the corresponding values from Roles as Text and Value. You can remove `Value = x.Id,` if you only have a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.